REF error in libreoffice calc, when trying to get address from another book
I need to get address from anoter book in LO calc. I do that in excell with success, but calc return me a ref error. I use 3 functions: match, index and cell.
calc
=CELL("address";INDEX('file:///C:/Users/vofan/Desktop/new/main_file.xlsx'#$main.H2:H970;MATCH(H2;'file:///C:/Users/vofan/Desktop/new/main_file.xlsx'#$main.H2:H970;0)))

I do that with ctl+shift+enter, and functios works independently but nothink help. Have any ideas?

Can you specify why you want to get the cell address of of another sheet? It does appear that CELL function doesn't work when referencing outside of the current document.
So maybe you'll need to achieve what you want to do in another way.

@H3coder So, I work with two documents, where are big lists of people. I choose anybody in the first document, and I need to find the same person in the second document. In my case, the best way is to use address in second doc + go to. Macros unavailable

Yeah, but why you need to get the textual result: 'file:///C:/Users/vofan/Desktop/new/main_file.xlsx'#$main.H10?  You know the file name and sheet, why not just use concat to construct the string and then use match to get the row number for you?

@H3coder, thanks! That what I need
